# asterisk queued call connect to agent defined in db

Tags: database, asterisk

Having a call in a queue, I need to disable dialing to an agent.
Instead I want to make a change to db (MySQL, from a web interface), define what sip should answer the call and make asterisk to dial that agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use func_odbc and dialplan to do dialling like you want

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc

unfortanly your task is not standart, so you can't do it without programming

Comment: As far as I understood, those queries are called in extensions, so an event triggers sql query (which is pretty straight forward), but where do I find info about a sql-query triggers an asterisk event? Thank you for you answer.

Comment: You can fire your own events via dialplan. No other way. Unfortnaly that very likly mean you have read asterisk book in full